# I want to convert an image into base64 encoding using buffer. As buffer is deprecated and it doesnt work in buffer.from ,bufffer.alloc()

Tags: node.js, electron

```
        var imgStr= new Buffer.from(img).toString('base64');
```

I have been using this, but it is not working. This is the code to convert the screenshot i have taken into base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `new`

```
var imgStr = Buffer.from(imgBuffer).toString('base64');
```